# call a function in ionic 3

Tags: html, function, typescript, ionic3

My problem seems to be very easy, but I kinda cant get the hang of it.

In my home.ts I have a function, which I'd like to call in my home.html

**Home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slides.slideTo(1, 500);
  }   
}
```

**Home.html**

```
<button onclick="goToSlide()">Slide 1</button>
```

I get an error that my function "goToSlide()" is unknown. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: `(click)="goToSlide()"`

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick` is the syntax for binding to the element's click event. This is similar to doing something like `button.addEventListener('click', () => window.goToSlide())`. Of course, `goToSlide` doesn't exist on `window` (globally) so you get an error.

Instead, you need to use Angular's template binding syntax. `()` syntax is used for output bindings -- that is when the component (`<button>` in this case) emits a click event it will run what is bound to it. So you use the syntax `(click)="goToSlide()"`. Under the hood this is something like:

```
this.content.querySelector('button').onClick(() => this.goToSlide())`.
```

So now it ends up calling your defined `goToSlide` function instead of the one on window.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to visit the documentation page:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/

Your **home.html** should look like this:

```
<!-- Bind the click event to a method -->
<button ion-button (click)="goToSlide()">
  Slide 1
</button>
```